# Is it possible to use UiPath on a server when Input Type Text is needed?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I am new to UIPath and RPA processes. I developped a process using UIPath and I deployed it on a windows server. My process connect to a website with login and password, then download a file to a directory. Everything is working great on my computer and on the server when I am logged in. But as soon as I log out from the server the process stop working when input user is needed.

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Which user input do you mean? The RPA should run on it's own.

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

1. As already mentioned by Conor, you will need Orchestrator to schedule your processes.
2. You will have to make sure that you are running the machine service robot installation and not the user service one.
   The former comes with the MSI Enterprise installer, the latter with the free Community Edition.
   The main difference is that the machine wide service will be able to initiate a remote session between the Orchestrator because it runs on your machine even if you do not have any active user session. The user service will turn of the moment you log out of the machine, which means it will break any process you might have running.
   See more about it here: https://docs.uipath.com/robot/docs/robot-service
3. After you have the Orchestrator with the machine wide service set up, it should work with the UiAutomations that do not require image recognition.
   For more information about that, you can see here:
   https://docs.uipath.com/robot/docs/windows-sessions
   (it goes in depth about the specific requirements to your infrastructure and the ways Orchestrator will initiate the user session depending on that setup)

Comment: That's not correct. You can also use the Windows Task tool to shedule Task in a specific period.

Comment: @kwoxer This is indeed possible, but based on what the OP wrote:

>But as soon as I log out from the server the process stop working when input user is needed.

I would say it is still required to have the machine wide service for it to work. If the matter concerns the Community Edition, it will not work when the user logs out. It *might* still work on a locked screen though, if you are willing to give it a try.

Comment: Yeah but a better solution is to remove that user inputs. As that would overall be nonsense in a Citrix process running in live environment.

Answer (score 0):

So from the sounds of it you're wanting to run the process while no one is logged in

Do do this you need to link up the RPA robot up to an instance of Orchestrator.

UiPath offer a free version of this at http://cloud.uipath.com/

From there you can schedule the job to run on the server without you having to log in.

There is also an option to use windows task scheduler however this isn't something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

> I developped a process using UIPath and I deployed it on a windows server.

Your Robot must be provisioned as an unattended Robot, and since it is a Windows Server, I assume you want to set its parameter "LoginToConsole" to true.

This is assuming that UiPath is installed using the msi (Enterprise) and the Robot service running (not configured in user mode.)
The Community installer can only run in User Mode, which means no process is listening to Orchestrator if your user is logged off.

In such a configuration, you should be able to start a new job either manually or via scheduler (trigger) from Orchestrator.